# How to change camera size in Unity 5.2.1

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am making a 2d game in unity and I've found that after updating to the new version I can no longer move the camera without changing the coords and the usual re size circles on the corners are gone. I am aiming to make a non scrolling platformer. I need the camera to be the right size and just stay still. Can anyone help me. I'm quite new to unity as you can probably tell.

Comment: Can you post the code you are using for the camera at the moment? Is the camera perspective or orthogonal?

Comment: I'm not using anything. I'm just using what's there at the start. I'm sure I've moved it before and resized it and everything.

Answer (score 2):

You can change any of the values in the inspector if memory serves. That's the info panel, usually on the right of the screen.

Also are you looking in the right screen? The game screen and the scene screen look similar but aren't in function. When you select the camera in the scene screen you should be able too see the gizmos (red green and blue arrows) as well as a projection of what the camera is looking at. Also if you have the camera selected a small window will appear in the bottom left of the scene screen showing you what it can see.

On a side note, you can't move the camera without changing the coordinates, they're intrinsic to the position of the camera, therefore if you move the camera, the coords have to change to accomodate the new position. Hope that's helpful.

Comment: Ok. I've found it now. The layout I was using changed Inspector to Debug. It seems almost the same.

Comment: @crabcrabcam If this answer helped you solve your problem, be sure to accept it. Alternatively, if you feel this question won't really have any value to future readers because it was just due to a misunderstanding about the layout, consider deleting it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you are going for a 2d game then, 
you can use :

```
private float yourDesiredSize = 0f;

void Awake()
{
   Camera.main.orthographicSize = yourDesiredSize;
}
```